# After upgrade of Bouncy Castle version 1.66 to 1.77 getting package org.bouncycastle.asn1.eac does not exist, any suggestion?

Tags: java, maven, bouncycastle

Upgraded the version of BC from `<groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId><artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId><version>1.66</version>` to `<groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId><artifactId>bcprov-jdk18on</artifactId><version>1.77</version>` in a Maven-based project but getting package deprecated *"package org.bouncycastle.asn1.eac does not exist"*,  so any suggestion for replacement of this package in 1.77 version?

Comment: Beginning in 1.69 **this package is in bcutil instead of bcprov**. Add (the matching version of) bcutil.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Please post answers as answers, not as comments.

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085 Yes it is in bcutil-jdk180n

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by [dave_thompson_085](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2868801/dave-thompson-085), since version 1.69, this package is in `bcutil` instead of `bcprov`. Add (the matching version of) `bcutil` to your classpath.